# SSIS DB2 ISeries Connection in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to extract data from a DB2 ISeries database using SSIS 2012. Unfortunately, I am not able to use Microsoft Ole DB provider for DB2 because that is only available in the Enterprise Edition. We are on the BI edition.

It seems like IBM provides Ole DB providers as well: for example IBM DB2 UDB for iSeries IBMDASQL OLE DB Provider. However, I am not sure what I need to download to get that. Is that a free component?

Answer (score 0):

OLEDB Provider for DB2 from this pack works ok on Standard and BI Edition
[Check Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)